# Issue with below snippet on boundary matchers regex (\b)

Tags: java, regex, set

My input:

```
 1. end 
 2. end of the day or end of the week 
 3. endline
 4. something 
 5. "something" end
```

Based on the above discussions, If I try to replace a single string using this snippet, it removes the appropriate words from the line successfully

```
public class DeleteTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
        File file = new File("C:/Java samples/myfile.txt");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("myfile1", ".txt", file.getParentFile());
        String delete="end";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp)));

        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            line = line.replaceAll("\\b"+delete+"\\b", "");
       writer.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went Wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

My output If I use the above snippet:(Also my expected output)

```
 1.  
 2. of the day or of the week
 3. endline
 4. something
 5. "something"
```

But when I include more words to delete, and for that purpose when I use Set, I use the below code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

    File file = new File("C:/Java samples/myfile.txt");
    File temp = File.createTempFile("myfile1", ".txt", file.getParentFile());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp)));

        Set<String> toDelete = new HashSet<>();
        toDelete.add("end");
        toDelete.add("something");

    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        line = line.replaceAll("\\b"+toDelete+"\\b", "");
    writer.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    writer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went Wrong");
    }
}
```

I get my output as: (It just removes the space)

```
 1. end
 2. endofthedayorendoftheweek
 3. endline
 4. something
 5. "something" end
```

Can u guys help me on this?

[Click here to follow the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832915/how-to-remove-a-particular-string-in-a-text-file-using-java)

Comment: Are you using Java 8 or 7?

Comment: I'm using Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an [**alternation group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) out of the set with

```
String.join("|", toDelete)
```

and use as

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\b(?:"+String.join("|", toDelete)+")\\b", "");
```

The pattern will look like

```
\b(?:end|something)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bfjwx2/1). Here, `(?:...)` is  a *non-capturing* group that is used to *group* several alternatives without creating a memory buffer for the capture (you do not need it since you remove the matches).

Or, better, compile the regex before entering the loop:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:" + String.join("|", toDelete) + ")\\b");
...
    line = pat.matcher(line).replaceAll("");
```

**UPDATE**:

To allow matching whole "words" that may contain special chars, you need to `Pattern.quote` those words to escape those special chars, and then you need to use unambiguous word boundaries, `(?<!\w)` instead of the initial `\b` to make sure there is no word char before and `(?!\w)` negative lookahead instead of the final `\b` to make sure there is no word char after the match.

In Java 8, you may use this code:

```
Set<String> nToDel = new HashSet<>();
nToDel = toDelete.stream()
    .map(Pattern::quote)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
String pattern = "(?<!\\w)(?:" + String.join("|", nToDel) + ")(?!\\w)";
```

The regex will look like [`(?<!\w)(?:\Q+end\E|\Qsomething-\E)(?!\w)`](https://regex101.com/r/Bfjwx2/2). Note that the symbols between `\Q` and `\E` is parsed as *literal symbols*.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. can you suggest a way to add things such as parenthesis and special characters inside regex pattern?

Comment: @venk: Do you mean you will have non-word (non-letter/digit/`_`) in the `toDelete` items? Then your word boundary based approach might fail to find the matches (if those non-word chars appear at the start/end as in `\b(?:+end|something-)\b`). You'd need to run `Pattern.quote` on all the items and then use `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` instead of the `\b`s.

Comment: @venk: See the updated answer. Please consider accepting if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Worked as expected. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not creating the correct regex for replacing the words in the set.

`"\\b"+toDelete+"\\b"` will produce this String `\b[end, something]\b` which is not what you need.

To fix that you can do something like this:

```
for(String del : toDelete){
    line = line.replaceAll("\\b"+del+"\\b", "");
}
```

What this does is to go through the set, produce a regex from each word and remove that word from the `line` String.

Another approach will be to produce a single regex from all the words in the set.

Eg:

```
String regex = "";
for(String word : toDelete){
   regex+=(regex.isEmpty() ? "" : "|") + "(\\b"+word+"\\b)";
}
....
line = line.replace(regex, "");
```

This should produce a regex that looks something like this: `(\bend\b)|(\bsomething\b)`

Comment: Thanks Titus. can you suggest a way to add things such as parenthesis and special characters inside regex?

Comment: @venk You will need to escape those characters using `\`. You can find more details about that [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10665057/1552587)