# Java regex exact match with question mark and word boundary

Tags: java, regex

In java, I am trying to determine if a user inputted string (meaning I do not know what the input will be) is contained exactly within another string, on word boundaries. So input of `the` should not be matched in the text `there is no match`. I am running into issues when there is punctuation in the inputted string however and could use some help.

With no punctuation, this works just fine:

```
String input = "string contain";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(input) + "\\b");

//both should and do match
System.out.println(p.matcher("does this string contain the input").find());
System.out.println(p.matcher("does this string contain? the input").find());
```

However when the input has a question mark in it, the matching with the word boundary doesn't seem to work:

```
String input = "string contain?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(input) + "\\b");

//should not match - doesn't
System.out.println(p.matcher("does this string contain the input").find());

//expected match - doesn't
System.out.println(p.matcher("does this string contain? the input").find());

//should not match - doesn't
System.out.println(p.matcher("does this string contain?fail the input").find());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @quackenator by adding `Pattern.quote()` you don't have to escape any special characters

Comment: Should `fail!?` be matched by `fail!` (leaving out a question mark in order to avoid confusion)

Comment: good question @steffen - yes - would want to treat any punctuation that isn't directly in the input as part of the "word boundary"

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43841961/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no word boundary between `?` and , because there's no adjacent word character; that's why your pattern doesn't match. You can change it to this:

```
Pattern.compile("(^|\\W)" + Pattern.quote(input) + "($|\\W)");
```

That matches begin of input or non-word character - pattern - end of input or non-word character. Or, better, you use a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)" + Pattern.quote(input) + "(?!\\w)");
```

This means, before and after your pattern there must not be a word character.

Comment: It's because if the `!` in-between, this is your word boundary. With your input sequence, "does this string contain?!fail the input", `string contain?!` does not match, but `string contain?` does. That's consistent.

Comment: sorry - deleted my comment before I saw your response as I realized my mistake. one more though, if the text ends with the input it doesn't seem to be matching, so in this example `does the string contain?` will fail but `does the string contain? ` (with a space) is good. One of these days I will learn my regex better!

Comment: @MrZorn Both do match. Read the last line: It matches, if there's not a following word character. This is not the case in both of your examples, so it works for both strings.

Comment: Ah - thought I grabbed the second pattern - that is working

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)" + Pattern.quote(input) + "(\\s|$)");
//---------------------------^^^^^^^----------------------------^^^^^^^
```

for Strings you will get :

```
does this string contain the input       -> false
does this string contain? the input      -> true
does this fail the input string contain? -> true
does this string contain?fail the input  -> false
string contain? the input                -> true
```

---

The idea is, matches the strings that contains your `input + space`, or `end with your input`.

Comment: Works partly on the right hand side as it only matches a space after `contain?`, but not e. g. another `?`. What about the left-hand side as in `¿does it?`.

Comment: @steffen you can try using `does this ?string contain? the input` it match correctly if `String input = "?string contain?";`

Comment: OK now you've lifted the left hand side to be as good as the partly woking right hand side ;-) Check with `does this string contain?? the input` and `string contain?`. It should match I guess, but it doesn't.

Comment: nope my friend this should not match based on the 3rd example of OP `//should not match - doesn't
System.out.println(p.matcher("does this string contain?fail the input").find());` you just replace the the `f` of fail by `?` i'm wrong @steffen :)

Comment: No, I'm afraid you're wrong. The third example should not match, because there's a following word character. It should match, if there's a non-word character coming. That's what this is all about.

Comment: mmm, we can understand from the OP then @steffen if i'm correct then i'm, else i will gives you my up-vote if your answer is correct, it is similar to mine, so i can't use it in my answer :) thank you any way for your information i appreciate it

Comment: The first problem I see with this solution is that it doesn't match if the text starts with the input "string contain? the input" - I guess I didn't include that explicit case in my examples

Comment: nope, it work i think you test with the oldest one, i already correct it @MrZorn it should be like this `Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)" + Pattern.quote(input) + "(\\s|$)");` after the comment of steffen

Answer (score 0):

You are matching using word boundaries: `\b`.

Java RegEx implementation deems following characters as word characters: 
`\w` := `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Any non-word characters are simply ones outside the above group 
`[^\w]` :=  `[^a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Word boundary is a transition from `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` to `[^a-zA-Z_0-9]` and vice-versa.

For input `"does this string contain? the input"` and literal pattern `\\b\\Qstring contain?\\E\\b` the last word boundary `\\b` falls within the input text into a transition from `?` to `<white space>` and therefore is not a valid **word** to **non-word** nor **non-word** to **word** transition as per above definitions, which means that it is **not a word boundary**.